# Möbius strip parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, rotations

[image]
This is from Pressley’s book. How to arrive at the parametric form using rotation matrices? The rotation about $z-axis$ can be obtained from basic rotation matrix but what about the rotation about the plane containing the point $P$ and the $z-axis$? Is second rotation a basic rotation about $y-axis$? 
EDIT: 
After applying rotation of $\theta$ about $z-axis$ and $\theta/2$ about $y-axis$ for the point $\left(1,0,t\right)$ I got $\left(cos(\theta)cos(\theta/2)-tsin(\theta/2), -sin(\theta), cos(\theta)sin(\theta/2)+tcos(\theta/2)\right)$. What am I missing?

Comment: It might be confusing that $(1,0,t)$ is initially rotated not around the $y$ axis but rather around its shift to $(1,0,0)$. Better first rotate $(0,0,t)$ by $-\theta/2$ around the $y$ axis to obtain $(-t\sin\frac\theta2,0,t\cos\frac\theta2)$; then shift by 1 in the $x$ direction to obtain $(1-t\sin\frac\theta2,0,t\cos\frac\theta2)$; finally rotate around the $z$ axis by $\theta$ to obtain $\sigma(t,\theta)$ as in the book.

Comment: What is this shift and rotation about the shift mean here? I’m having trouble with this. Is not $\left(1,0,t\right)$ just a point which is to be rotated? Why think of rotation of $\left(0,0,t\right)$ about it shift? Is it not just a translation? How can I visualise this?

Comment: What I call shift is what you call translation. As a first move you may either rotate $(1,0,t)$ around the translated $y$ axis, that is, through the axis parallel to the $y$ axis and going through $(1,0,0)$. Or, easier, you may first rotate $(0,0,t)$ around the $y$ axis and then translate the result by $1$ in the $x$ direction. The combined result will be the same. After that, you rotate around the $z$ axis.

Comment: Thank you. Another thing I’m wondering is that, when we talk about rotating a point $\left(x,y,z\right)$ say about $z-axis$ do we have to think first about translating the point from origin to $\left(x,y,z\right)$? In general there is no point in rotating the origin, so why don’t we think of just rotation without translation? In the previous example what goes wrong if I forget translation and just rotate $\left(1,0,t\right)$? Why in this case I’m not getting the right answer?

Comment: Center of the interval $(1,0,t)$ is not the origin, it is $(1,0,0)$. If you rotate it around the $y$ axis its center will not stay fixed. For center to stay fixed you have to rotate around the translated axis parallel to the $y$ axis and going through $(1,0,0)$. This is the same as first rotate $(0,0,t)$ whose center is the origin around the $y$ axis and then translate the result. After that, you just rotate around the $z$ axis, without any further translation.

Comment: In the book: "...after $P$ has rotated by an angle $\theta$ around the $z$-axis, $\mathcal L$ should have rotated by $\theta/2$ *around* $P$...". It should have rotated around $P$, which is the midpoint of $\mathcal L$, not around the origin, which is not.

Answer (score 1):

We have a combination of two rotations: In time $\Theta  = 2\pi$ the segment $\mathcal L$ rotates with speed $1/2$ in the $xz$-plane (which is spanned by the $z$-axis and $\mathcal L$) around its midpoint $P = (1,0,0)$, and the $xz$-plane rotates with speed $1$ around the $z$-axis.

Note that we must assume that the segment $\mathcal L$ has the form $\{(1,0)\} \times [-r,r]$ with $r < 2$ (otherwise $\mathcal L$ would intersect $\mathcal C$ in two points at rotation time $\theta = \pi$).

A plane rotation by an angle $\phi$ around the origin is given by the matrix $$A(\phi)  = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \phi & -\sin \phi\\\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{pmatrix}$$
A rotation in the $xz$-plane only affects the first and third coordinate of a vector, in particular we see that the vector $(0,0,t)$ is rotated to $(-t\sin \phi,0,t\cos \phi)$.

At time $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ the point $P_t = (1,0,t) = P + (0,0,t) \in \mathcal L$ has reached the position $P_t(\theta) = P + (-t\sin(\theta/2),0,t\cos(\theta/2) ) = (1 - t\sin(\theta/2),0,t\cos(\theta/2))$.

The rotation of the point $P_t(\theta) = (P_1,0,P_3)$ around the $z$-axis only affects the first two coordinates and at time $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ we reach
$$P_t'(\theta) = (P_1\cos \theta,P_1\sin \theta ,P_3) = ((1 - t\sin(\theta/2))\cos \theta,(1 - t\sin(\theta/2))\sin \theta,t\cos(\theta/2)) .$$
In particular you see that $P_t'(2\pi) = (1,0,-t)$.